# iOS app rejected because of location issue (4.4)

Tags: ios, geolocation, appstore-approval

I'm desperate because my app has been rejected for following reason:

```
4.4.Location data can only be used when directly relevant to the features and services provided by the App to the user or to support approved advertising uses
```

What does it mean exactly?

My app is designed for an event.
It has a module: when the user opens it a map is displayed and multiple pins are shown to indicate the important places of the event to navigate to them - switching to Apple Maps (such as Congress Venue, Hotels fore the delegates, Conference Gala Dinner..)

The Apple review team hast rejected the app because... I can't understand why!
I've tried to explain the reviewer that this functionality is important for the app. He replays by pasting and copying the same answer he already gave me with an attached screenshot where the app asks for the user authorization to get his location..

What is the problem with geo location?
Some more explanation?

Comment: Does your map display the user's location?  Does your app do anything else with the user's location? - Alert them when they are nearby a point of interest?  Provide distances to areas etc. Did you include a value for `NSLocationUsageDescription` in your Info.plist to explain why you use location?  If all you are displaying is a map you don't need the user's location

Comment: The only thing that I do is to display a point of interest (not where the user is) and then clicking on it the app switches on Apple Maps, using user location to navigate to the point. Is not enough? I can't image many other ways to use geolocation..
Also I have on line other apps with the same equal code with no problem: that is strange!

Comment: Then you don't need to request the users location - you can simply pass the destination item to `openMapsWithItems` and maps will assume that the user's current location is the start point